# How can I deserialize a comma-separated JSON string as a vector of separate strings?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I would like to deserialize my incoming data from Rocket with Serde with my own deserializer for one field. The `tags` field is originally a string and should be deserialized into a `Vec<String>`. The format of the string is more-or-less comma-separated values with a special treatment of some characters.

The documentation of Serde is completely unclear for me how to treat that case. The basic structure of `tags_deserialize` I just copied from the [documentation](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#deserialize_with).

Currently my code is as follows:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
pub struct TaskDataJson {
    pub name: String,
    pub description: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "tags_deserialize")]
    pub tags: Vec<String>
}

fn tags_deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<String>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    ??? - How do I access the string coming from the response and how do I set it??
}
```

A sample of incoming data is:

```
{
    "name":"name_sample",
    "description":"description_sample",
    "tags":"tag1,tag2,tag5"
}
```

where this should lead to:

```
name = "name_sample";
description = "description_sample"
tags = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag5"]
```

Comment: I don't understand, this is just json, why not use serde_json ? And then just parse `tags` field *after* with whatever you like. serde is not mean to be a parser.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, this is also my backup plan if this does not work directly with serde. However, I would like to have a more _elegant_ solution especially because I already basically did the same vice-versa for my output data and there I got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround is to deserialize the string sequence "tag1,tag2,tag3" as a `String` value and then convert it to a `Vec` of strings, for example:

```
fn tags_deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<String>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let str_sequence = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    Ok(str_sequence
        .split(',')
        .map(|item| item.to_owned())
        .collect())
}
```

Comment: Thank you @attdona . Your solution works great :D 
The only thing left was that I was at first not sure which error to return when deserializing does not work but I found out that `return Err(serde::de::Error::custom("Custom error string"));` is sufficient for me.